VB Excel Error when referencing external website; Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range
I have a main Excel page (we will call it dashboard)
It has cells that link to hidden sheets in my VB and it also has cells that link to websites. All the internal stuff works fine finding other sheets. It is also successful going out to the websites by clicking but it always throws up

Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range

when I click on one of the cells that references an external website. Internal pages are fine. Furthermore, if I go into one of the other sheets and reference a website through a link... no error and works fine. It's just from that main dashboard page that it doesn't like external linking.
Code on Dashboard page:
Option Explicit

Dim bFlag As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim SH As Worksheet
Dim arr As Variant

    If bFlag = True Then Exit Sub
    arr = Split(Target.SubAddress, "!")
    Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0))
    SH.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    bFlag = True
    Target.Follow
    bFlag = False
    End Sub

Code on all other hidden sheets:
Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Me.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End Sub

Tried many different things and I know it's just something I'm not adding correctly to the dashboard code.

Maybe there is not sheet with that name. Try Debug.Print arr(0)

@KenWhite: Split always returns a 0-based array, so that's not the issue here.

Your problem is that your code doesn't distinguish between internal links (=links to a worksheet/cell) and external links (links to anything else, eg a web site).
When you click on an internal link, target.address is empty and target.SubAddress holds the worksheet/cell address - that's handled correctly.
However, when you click on an external link, target.SubAddress is empty. The statement arr = Split(Target.SubAddress, "!") will return an undefined array (Ubound(arr) is -1), and using arr(0) will issue the runtime error.
Just update your code that it checks if SubAddress is filled:
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim arr As Variant
    If bFlag = True Then Exit Sub
    
    If Target.SubAddress <> "" Then
        arr = Split(Target.SubAddress, "!")
        Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0))
        SH.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
    
    bFlag = True
    Target.Follow
    bFlag = False
End Sub


I appreciate the information. I'm just not certain "how" to do that. Can you let me know what specifically I should change it to? I'm sorry, I'm just not an expert at this.

Just have a look to the code I posted - it checks if SubAddress is filled. If not, it simply skips the part to make any worksheet visible.

I tried it exactly and still gives same error. The line that highlights in yellow is the Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0))

It does actually open the website just fine but it always throws that error and I have to close that box

Even with the If-statement? What is the content of SubAddress when this happens (check with the debugger)?

'=========>>
Option Explicit
Dim bFlag As Boolean
'--------->>
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
Dim SH As Worksheet
Dim arr As Variant
If bFlag = True Then Exit Sub
If Target.SubAddress <> "" Then
    arr = Split(Target.SubAddress, "!")
    Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0))
    SH.Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If

bFlag = True
Target.Follow
bFlag = False

End Sub
'<<=========
In debug it just highlights that one line of Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0)) in yellow.

In debug it just highlights that one line of Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr(0)) in yellow

I understand the line of error, but what is the content of Target.SubAddress when the error happens?

Ah! I just tired something since you are asking. I put in a web address to https://www.google.com and it works perfect. My error is showing up with my https://docs.google.com with all the stuff after the docs.google.com/2093u02399023u02. If I just go https://docs.google.com it also works fine. It must be something with all the characters referencing the actual google document? Now that is really strange

I don't get it. When you click on a regular link (no matter how complicated it is), Target.SubAddress should be empty. When the error occurs: What is the content of Target.SubAddress so that it hits the code inside the If-statement?

I'd just have to do a google meet with you and share my screen. I have no clue why it's doing this.....

haywoc@pm.me
Let me know if I can share my screen and show you exactly what it does.

I give up - if you don't answer a simple question, I cannot help you. Do you know the basics of the VBA debugger?
